# Uniswap swap doesn't give equivalent swapping price

Tags: uniswap, testing

I'm using a uniswap end to end test but couldn't find the equivalent value of swap with my tests. I'm mimicking the DAI EOA address to achieve result through ganache-cli but it's giving me a wrong swap value For an instance I'm swapping 100 DAI with ALCX and in uniswap web it gives me value of 2.07

[image: Uniswap Web Page]

But on my testing smart contract it gives me weird value at all which is **30**

**UNISWAP SMART CONTRACT**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "./interfaces/Uniswap.sol";

contract TestUniswap {
  address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER =
    0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
  address private constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

  function swap(
    address _tokenIn,
    address _tokenOut,
    uint _amountIn,
    uint _amountOutMin,
    address _to
  ) external {
    IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountIn);
    IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, _amountIn);

    address[] memory path;
    if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
      path = new address[](2);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = _tokenOut;
    } else {
      path = new address[](3);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = WETH;
      path[2] = _tokenOut;
    }

    IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(
      _amountIn,
      _amountOutMin,
      path,
      _to,
      block.timestamp
    );
  }

  function getAmountOutMin(
    address _tokenIn,
    address _tokenOut,
    uint _amountIn
  ) external view returns (uint) {
    address[] memory path;
    if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
      path = new address[](2);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = _tokenOut;
    } else {
      path = new address[](3);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = WETH;
      path[2] = _tokenOut;
    }

    // same length as path
    uint[] memory amountOutMins =
      IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);

    return amountOutMins[path.length - 1];
  }
}
```

TEST UNISWAP JS FILE

```
const BN = require("bn.js");
const { sendEther } = require("./util");
const {  WBTC, WBTC_WHALE, DAI, DAI_WHALE,WETH } = require("./config");

const IERC20 = artifacts.require("IERC20");
const TestUniswap = artifacts.require("TestUniswap");

contract("TestUniSwap",(accounts)=>{
    const WHALE = DAI_WHALE; //MIMICKING DAI EOA
    const AMOUNT_IN =new BN(10).pow(new BN(18)).mul(new BN(100));
    
    const AMOUNT_OUT_MIN = 1;
    const TOKEN_IN = DAI;
    const TOKEN_OUT = "0xdBdb4d16EdA451D0503b854CF79D55697F90c8DF"; //ALCX Contract Address
    const TO = accounts[0];
    console.log(TO);



    it("should swap", async ()=>{
        const tokenIn = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_IN);
        const tokenOut = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_OUT);
        const randToken = await IERC20.at(WETH);
        const testUniswap = await TestUniswap.new();
        console.log(`Before ${await tokenOut.balanceOf(TO)}`);
        // console.log(`Before ${web3.eth.getBalance(this)}`);
        
        await tokenIn.approve(testUniswap.address, AMOUNT_IN, {from: WHALE});

        await testUniswap.swap(
            tokenIn.address,
            tokenOut.address,
            AMOUNT_IN,
            AMOUNT_OUT_MIN,
            TO,
            {
                from :WHALE,
            }
        );

        console.log(`out ${await tokenOut.balanceOf(TO)}`);
        // console.log(`out ${await tokenOut.balanceOf(TO)}`);
        
        // console.log(`out ${await new BN(10).pow(new BN(18)).div(new BN(tokenOut.balanceOf(TO)))}`);

    });

})
```

GANACHE MAINNET FORK TO MIMICK

```
ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MY_API_KEY --unlock 0xF977814e90dA44bFA03b6295A0616a897441aceC --networkId 999
```

But when i run the test, the test gets passed through but it returns incorrect swap value from DAI TO ALCX which is **30** that is absolutely wrong. Am i missing something, i'm beating my head but couldn't get past of it.

[image: test result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons, Why you're not find same rate at every swap. because in testing scenarios we haven't add sufficient liquidity to remove these issue. at every swap resevers got change, 1 reserve increased and 1 got decreases, this increment and decrement cause price change at every swap